# Nuxt Authentification parameter for token

Tags: azure, vue.js, nuxt.js, azure-ad-msal, nuxt-auth

Guys! Currently I have a problem sending request for token. I'm using nuxtJS **@nuxtjs/auth-next** module. It's working great, but i faced a problem not sending **client_secret**. This request for authorization goes to **AZURE AD**. My config:

```
msalAzure: {
    scheme: 'oauth2',
    endpoints: {
      authorization: `${process.env.VUE_APP_AZURE_AUTHORITY}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`,
      token: `${process.env.VUE_APP_AZURE_AUTHORITY}/oauth2/v2.0/token`,
    },
    token: {
      property: 'access_token',
      type: 'Bearer',
      maxAge: 1800,
      global: true,
    },
    refreshToken: {
      property: 'refresh_token',
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
    },
    responseType: 'code',
    responseMode: 'query',
    grantType: 'authorization_code',
    accessType: 'offline',
    // ******** change this for your Application (Client) ID ********
    redirectUri: process.env.VUE_APP_AZURE_REDIRECT_URI,
    clientId: process.env.VUE_APP_AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.VUE_APP_AZURE_SECRET,
    codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
    scope: ['offline_access', 'openid', 'profile', 'User.Read'],
    autoLogout: false,
  },
```

payload for token where i need to paste client_secret:

```
code: 0.AS8AovV86_Vz5UuO2sAmSstunkCOoPABwrREiFppI0jDAkwvAMU.AgABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrAgDs_wQA9P9iCom2SEms5Su-Au0Vl3-GG9W1y4OUDaCIF0y4xmd9H4TIFgNmGW0K425Ji9zN2xAKf6VaQ6q8EiBI9AXdNv8DqZMCDTs9qWBETVF2JftuXIeazYEu-eqmqkNMAp0arJ9Mf7GAnrWHCa5wDYpwXNCI9tQ7nqmuHzp3aRjldsN77_5bq1eqgq7PvU5KaNGmxmkYe96_Xzeqqu-9FlJGpNlJ6y8J1BZtW4wVlRrOn6-n1aIFqOcAGp00kR53uiWExjAIZMdPIdjW8BgD2O6ZY8l_779ArkGrUT6zYEjs_YRb7yg2EqgqnL7ZVBVhoufAxbtsRiGbtvA5_Usp4rPf5Bxft3evNPCYA33PWsJUNSOiq4PeOFfpPHjlA7zwkouwfXnmrswONQatNl8xM3BQuduwf1mAszZQKl-skR9-XlvPxj66aGpdl3_hzIqWCqSbSbmIK0e40-Ob4r7XuNb1qoy7opbJfDp1FmTl6WHRexEE1RPBw_XER7kb6kBrXYnTaYPxHuIcVZeYdYS58o_8kMwVVO-qsTb1N7RyT52DgiHB22yUNZaPwpyB6k1wr9hSbhPT6jkIMbuud__EHrmvRVqQaTY1CHAVG8H1wd3CKJCWTFR9sajos17VybxJ4VT_r7ySRUH2UQarOU0ooTlyO32P7iBO5K9CU3V4XrRAQCiVfIMNcbcU1WWlF_eTkEX9bXnHN6houQtLhVndm8y1XIJ21_qh4pVB3wpm0HrXXSGdYgvrM2Td7zx6EZPKK1CmJMgnEii5w1U09occn-CLHLBZAv6_vE8hNCS3VqN20YAvO2vhiLYalS4JmNHG3Z4CVuJ3K7fz5B23kA
client_id: f0a08e40-c201-44b4-885a-692348c3024c
redirect_uri: http://localhost:8005/login/submit/
response_type: code
audience: 
grant_type: authorization_code
```

Sending request for strategy (this params goes for authorize only):

```
@click="$auth.loginWith('msalAzure', { params: { client_secret: process.env.VUE_APP_AZURE_SECRET,},})"
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your `process.env.VUE_APP_AZURE_SECRET` at the client side. Action click and event trigger is client side.

Please try public runtime config with `Public Runtime Config` - Value of this object is accessible from both client and server using $config.

At `nuxt.config.js`

```
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  azureClientSecret: process.env.VUE_APP_AZURE_SECRET
}
```

Then you can use this value by access `$config.azureClientSecret` at your code as below:

```
@click="$auth.loginWith('msalAzure', { params: { client_secret: $config.azureClientSecret,},})"
```

But I think you should avoid put your secret key at the client side.

Comment: Thank you @iamduy! But the main problem that it sends secret to authorize request. After processing authorize request it sends me PKCE code that has to send token request which sends payload that I wrote in my question, I need to customize this request by sending secret. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: @Creoad
I'm sorry for the late reply.

>> "payload for token where i need to paste client_secret":

Do you have your own backend server?

>> "I need to customize this request by sending secret":

I think you should store your secret token on your server and then authorize request from your server.

After authorized request, you can send PKCE code from your server to your client.